# How come c# can return the object and c++ can't when popping from STL containers?

Tags: c#, c++, stl, stack

In C#, when you pop from a stack, it removes the object from the stack and returns the object.

However, in C++ because of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhanli/archive/2010/06/29/c-tips-why-the-pop-method-of-stl-stack-does-not-return-a-value.aspx, the pop function will not return the object.

What makes C# be able to do something that C++ can't?
Or is it more like C# does not care if this exception case happens or not? "If operator= or copy constructor throws exception, then we will be in trouble: the stack's internal state has been changed, but we have not get the popped element." (from the link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's that in C++ you're returning a copy of the item in the collection, but in C# you're returning a reference. Returning the reference is guaranteed not to throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Because in C#, the operation is "cheap" -- it's just returning a byte-for-byte copy of the struct or object reference.

In C++, returning the object is expensive -- it requires making a *copy* of the object itself by calling the copy constructor, which can involve practically *anything* the user has specified must happen, including (but not limited to) allocating new resources and destroying old ones.

(For example, imagine if the object to be returned was a binary tree. Copying it would be **very** expensive compared to copying, say, an `int`.)

C++11 *could* have used "move semantics" to avoid copying objects, but move semantics were introduced *after* `pop_back` was, and they didn't bother changing it.

Comment: The argument for not returning from `pop()` type functions is not efficiency, but exception safety.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I don't see why they're mutually exclusive? They're both valid arguments to me.

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive, but without the exception safety guarantees it would have been desirable to provide popping methods that return a copy of the element being popped. The "give me a reference to the element so I can copy it, then I will pop" idiom is quite clumsy, and difficult to synchronise in multi-thread environments.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm having trouble parsing what you're saying. Are you saying if exception safety wasn't a concern, then they would have done this? Because I don't think so.

Comment: I am saying exactly that: they would have provided some popping methods that return and pop.

Comment: @juanchopanza: And how exactly is exception safety preventing them from providing these other methods that return and pop?

Comment: It is explained briefly in the link provided by OP. [This boost article](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) might also shed some light.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ugh, you're not making sense. You're telling me that if exception safety wasn't a concern, *"they would have provided **some** popping methods that return and pop"*. That means you're claiming exception safety requirements prevent them from creating ***any*** such popping methods! When I ask you why, you link me to a page that says exception safety prevents the **`pop` method itself** from being able to return the value. How in the world does the latter explain the former? There is nothing about exception safety that prevents them from having had **some** such popping method.

Comment: Exception safety prevents `pop` from returning the value. No concern for exception safety means you can have a single method that pops and returns. I said "some popping methods" is because one would still might want to keep a non-returning pop anyway, and because there are different pops depending on the container (pop_front, pop_back, plain pop etc.) And they don't want to provide non-exception safe pop methods, because that is the policy, which is where we started.

Comment: @juanchopanza: *"Exception safety prevents `pop` from returning the value."* Now you're going in a circle. Isn't that exactly what I agreed with [in my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581095/how-come-c-sharp-can-return-the-object-and-c-cant-when-popping-from-stl-conta/19581118?noredirect=1#comment29062214_19581118), when I said exception safety is as equally valid of a concern for `pop` as copying? I don't see what's wrong with anything I've said.

Comment: You said this: "Are you saying if exception safety wasn't a concern, then they would have done this?..."

Comment: @juanchopanza: The word *"this"* in my comment refers to your previous comment, *"provide popping methods that return a copy of the element being popped"*. The word "this" is **not** referring to some imaginary phrase like *"provide a `pop` method that returns a copy of the element being popped"*. i.e. I was saying that, unlike what you claimed, they could very well have provided "popping methods" *other than `pop`* for this purpose; exception safety concerns don't prevent that.

Comment: Exception safety does not prevent providing exception unsafe methods? OK.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Uh yeah, no, it doesn't. It's obviously your job as a programmer to be responsible and use the right method for the right purpose. As long as there are safe methods to give you the guarantees you need, the existence of other unsafe (but perhaps more efficient, easy to use, etc.) methods causes no issues whatsoever.